# What other feature extractors can be used with the BagOfFeatures function in MATLAB?

Tags: image, matlab, feature-extraction, sift

I'm developing a program that uses BagOfFeatures but I want to try it with different feature extractors such as SIFT and HOG to compare the results. Is there any way I can integrate this extractors and use them as the extractor for BagOfFeatures?

Answer (score 0):

I assume this [bagOfFeatures() option](https://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/bagoffeatures-class.html#buo5kpa) is what you're looking for? [This page lists a couple of built-in feature extractors](https://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/local-feature-extraction.html) such as HOG, and you should be able to emulate the function I/O for any custom ones you want to develop.

[Here is a tutorial](https://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ug/create-a-custom-feature-extractor.html) from the MATLAB documentation on using custom extractors with `bagOfFeatures`.